# Axios response/return is getting data but need indexing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have a working axios return, showing that my objects are holding the correct returned data. But my issue is this: The data that is coming to the return, while correct, is not grouped by ID, so even though I only have 4 unique items I get 8 rows in my return because each item has a name and a comment which are returned separately. The issue here is that for each ID/Item, I want to show the Name and other top level data in an HTML table but if you click on it then the modal would show more sub level data, like the comment.

For example, I'm getting this in the return:

```
0:{
  item_id: "123",
  item_comment_type: "Title",
  item_type: "2",
  item_comment:"This is an Item"
}
1:{
  item_id: "123",
  item_comment_type: "Comment",
  item_type: "2",
  item_comment:"This is a comment"
}
2:{
  item_id: "1245",
  item_comment_type: "Title",
  item_type: "3",
  item_comment:"This is a new Item"
}
3:{
  item_id: "1245",
  item_comment_type: "Comment",
  item_type: "3",
  item_comment:"This is a new Comment"
}
```

So I want one section to only show 2 rows since I only have 2 items, and it should show the item ID and item Title, but then if it is clicked and the modal pops up I still want all data associated with it to show there. I really just want to group these things by ID so that at the top level I have the ID and the comment if the comment type is title, and everything else in a level below it.

Here's the axios call:

```
axios.get('/home/items' )
        .then((response) => {

            const events = response.data.map(item => {
            return {
              id: item.item_id,
              title: item.item_comment, // if item_comment_type is Title
              comment: item.item_comment, // if item_comment_type is Comment
              type: item.item_type
            };
          });

          this.dateEvents = events;
          this.events = events;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function () {

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to map the items based on item_id.

```
let events = {};
response.data.forEach(item => {
    if (typeof events[item.item_id] === 'undefined') {
        events[item.item_id] = {
            id: item.item_id,
            comments: [],
            title: '',
        };
    }
    if (item.item_comment_type === 'Title') {
        events[item.item_id].title = item.item_comment;
    } else {
        events[item.item_id].comments.push(item.item_comment);
    }
});
```

This will give you an object, indexed by item_id, having title and a comments array which you can then loop using v-for (assuming you're using Vue.JS since this question is tagged that way).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem's solution can be obtained my storing mapping of `item_id` to respective data.

Suppose after your `events` array is being structured, loop accordingly to store `item_id` as key and array of respective grouping for that ID. Also update array for respective accordingly.

```
let newObj = {};
events.forEach((item,index) => {
  console.log('item',item)
  newObj[item.item_id] = newObj[item.item_id] ? [...newObj[item.item_id],item]:[item]
});
```

Comment: So then would I set events and dateEvents to newObj?

Comment: Yes if your purpose is same for `dateEvents` as you've mentioned and then so